# Is there a ways to override the DevExpress filter choices in GridControl?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am currently programming in Visual Studio 2010 within VB.NET and am using DevExpress v10.2, specifically WinForms. In the DevExpress GridControl at runtime you can click on the right side of the column header and choose which values in the column you want to show.

For example if your table contained:

```
Name1   Checked
Name2   Unchecked
Name3   Unchecked
Name4   Checked
```

Then if you click on the right side of the checkbox's header you can choose checked (or unchecked) and it would display only the data that is checked (or unchecked). In this case with checked you would have:

```
Name1   Checked
Name4   Checked
```

I was wondering if there was some way to override the names so instead of letting me choose checked or unchecked I could override it with 'owned' and 'rented' or 'active' and 'inactive' based on what the checkbox represents in that specific column.

**Edit**

Working with DevExpress WinForms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify which technology you were using; here are a couple options:

1. [ASP.NET](http://devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q224301.aspx)
2. [WinForms](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument994)

Comment: That seems to tell you how to make the visible or not. What I want to do is rename the value... I tried but it is saying that changing the value is readonly and I don't know how to change the string it displays.

Comment: The values are based on what values are contained in the grid. How those values appear in the filter is based on the value of FilterItem.Text. You should be able to look at the value of each of your FilterItems and remap how they appear in the filter (as shown in the sample)

Comment: Works beautifully. Thank you. Oh since you seem to know this very well do you know how to get it to go invisible or unenabled. I am using ComboBox.Items rather than CheckedComboBox.Items and its telling me that it doesn't have 'enabled' or 'visible'.

Comment: ComboBox.Items is a collection of objects. If you are putting CheckBoxes in them, then you would cast the item to a CheckBox, then you would see it. (ex: (e.ComboBox.Items[0] as CheckBox).Enabled))